# imagerotate() is not working

Tags: php, image, gd, image-rotation

imagerotate() function is not working for me. See the code below

```
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

    // Rotate
    $source = imagerotate($source, 90, 0);

    // Output
    imagejpeg($source);

    // Free the memory
    imagedestroy($source);
```

This is what is get from phpinfo regarding gd

> GD Support    enabled GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible) FreeType
>
> Support   enabled FreeType Linkage    with freetype FreeType Version
>
> 2.3.11 GIF Read Support     enabled GIF Create Support  enabled JPEG Support    enabled libJPEG Version     6b PNG Support  enabled libPNG
>
> Version   1.2.49 WBMP Support     enabled XPM Support     enabled libXpm
>
> Version   30411 XBM Support   enabled

I searched a lot for the answer, but didn't get the correct answer for this.

**can any suggest a solution for this? any help will be appreciated**

Comment: Have you tried another jpg file? Code works for me. Maybe you forgot the headers? `header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");`

Comment: Works for me too. What does 'not working' mean? How do you know it's not working? Does the image render, just not rotated? Do you get a blank page? Make sure you've enabled all error reporting and check the PHP error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who replied to my question.

It was actually working. It was not working for me because of an error  generated, which prevented the execution imagerotate function.

Thanks once again.